# Where to save new model file in laravel 5.3 and how to call model method from controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Where to save new model file created in laravel 5.3 in /app/http folder or in /app folder 
And how I will call the method in it from controller ?
How to include the model in controller?
Laravel 5.3

Comment: RTFM https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Save them in `app/models` folder and you can access it by constucting it,Make sure you have ran composer dump-autolad

```
public function __construct(YourModel $model) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->model = $model;
}
```

in your code simply `model->test();`it should work.

Comment: use App\Users; include in controller and created a function in model "Users"   in that created a method test how to call it??

Answer (score 0):

You create the folder `Models`wherever you want and add your files as you wish, just make sure to properly namespace it. [As long as Composer can autoload the class.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure)

You can manually create app/Models/User.php and just make sure to namespace it:

```
namespace App\Models;

class User {
    // your code
}
```

And to call the model method from a controller use the namespace of the model:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\YourModel;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class YourModelController extends Controller
{
    public function whatever(){

        $yourmodel->method();

    }
}
```